# Get the variable of a json request outside the function (jquery)

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I feel pretty stupid asking this but how can I get the variable crdnts outside the function

```
$(function() {
    var coordinates = {
        LoadDefault: function() {
             $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', '', function(json) {
                var crdnts = json.latitude + "," + json.longitude;
                //alert(crdnts);//this works
                return crdnts;
            });
        }
    };
    alert(coordinates.LoadDefault());//I would like to get the crdnts variable here.
});
```

or

http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/Lv3YD/

Comment: That is because Ajax is asynchronous. The usual way is to put the `alert()` into the success callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript ajax is asynchronous. so you need to use callbacks:

```
$(function() {
    var coordinates = {
        LoadDefault: function() {
             $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', '', function(json) {
                var crdnts = json.latitude + "," + json.longitude;
                call_alert(crdnts); //callback
            });
        }
    };
    function call_alert(cr){
         alert(cr);
    }
    coordinates.LoadDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks it was this callback that I was looking for.  I figured that due to the async nature it was not possible but I didn't know how to do this callback function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your Ajax call is asynchronous, so you cannot predict when will it return.

The only thing you can do is doing something with it in the success callback, or [set your Ajax to be synchronous](http://www.todayisearched.com/2010/02/jquery-getjson-async-false.html) if it is a choice (in this case all JS execution will wait until the request is finished).

For example, you can call a function when the Ajax call successfully finished:

```
$(function() {
    var coordinates = {
        LoadDefault: function() {
             $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', '', function(json) {
                var crdnts = json.latitude + "," + json.longitude;
                callSomething(crdnts);
            });
        }
    };

    function callSomething(x) {
        alert(x);
    }
});
```