# Return ajax variable with external URL

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the variable value from an ajax request. Here is my code:

```
country_locator = function() {
    var country_iso;

    $.getJSON("https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?", "", function(json) {
        country_iso = json.address.country_code;
    });

    return country_iso;
}
```

I also tried:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            country_iso = data.address.country_code;
        }
    });
```

and

```
var country_iso;
country_locator = function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?", "", function(json) {
        country_iso = json.address.country_code;
    }).success/complete(function() {
        return country_iso;
    });
}
```

but with `alert(country_locator());` I get an undefined variable error.

I have found this link: [Get the variable of a json request outside the function (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443115/get-the-variable-of-a-json-request-outside-the-function-jquery) but didn't manage to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

because `$.getJSON` is an async function. `country_iso` won't fill untill your request ajax complete.

I recommend use to do this using [deferred](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.Deferred):

```
var country_iso;
country_locator = function() {    
    $.getJSON("https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?", "", function(json) {
        country_iso = json.address.country_code;
    });
}

country_locator().success(function() {
    // do your logic here and use `country_iso` variable here.
});
```

[Read More About Deferred](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.Deferred)

[Read More About getJSON](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.getJSON)

Comment: Thanks Mohamad for your very fast reply, i've always been impressed by the reactivity of stackoverflow community :)
Also, sorry i forgot to mention that I did try the success function (edited initial post), but still no positive result :( I'll try your solution now and get back to you

Comment: umm, adding the country_locator().success returns an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined